# What does 'bend angle' of DNA mean?

Tags: dna

Literally, what does the ***'bend angle'*** of DNA mean?
I did some googling but I couldn't understand it.
How is it defined?

Comment: Welcome to S.E. Biology. Please 1. Give us a link to a publication in the which you encountered the term (so we can see its use in context) and 2. Quote to us what you found by googling, telling us what part of the explanation you did not understand. That will help us provide an appropriate answer.